# URL rewriting without htaccess (no multi-pages)

Tags: javascript, php, url-rewriting

I have a single page that display stuff depending on a parameter :

```
domain.com/index.php/?id=foo
```

works as well as

```
domain.com/?id=foo
```

I would like to rewrite the parameter so that

```
domain.com/foo
```

also works.

BUT I have no access to the htaccess. I can use PHP and JS/jQuery.

I'm pretty sure this is not possible but I would like a confirmation.

**edit** : I would like to avoid the multi-pages trick, as the parameter is just a simple js variable and nothing else. These variables will change on a regular basis so I don't want any hardcoded information.

Comment: Is `domain.com/#foo` acceptable?  You can then use Javascript to parse the hashtag, and if you need a bit more of a robust URL routing solution you can try something like `Sammy.js` http://sammyjs.org/

Comment: Your requirements are not fulfillable with the given constraints.

Comment: Thanks you should make it an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well then you have to change the way of setting your files. I meean ..

IF i have this url:  **domain.com/?id=foo** -> It means THAT I have 1 general INDEX, and I am including that FOO page .. (more simple: your index is openning a dir, that is called **FOO** and gets the content ot it)  To make it like this : **domain.com/foo** , you have to change your way file structure. You still have to make a different folder for each page, but  they HAVE TO be in the root dir.

Example for **domain.com/foo**:

```
  root dir /
    -> index/ 
        => index.php
    -> foo/ 
        => index.php
```

Got it ?